# AngularJs issue with hiding table heads

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create angular application of football scores in which user can checkmark on 2015 and can get info for only matches held in 2015, so when i click on 2015 checkbox, matches held only in 2015 are shown but the matches which are not held in 2015 are also shown with blank tables head which i am not able to hide with angular, my problem can be solved if those blank table heads can be hidden, please download and run the server then you will clearly understand the problem. Download Link: http://www99.zippyshare.com/v/F44Cr5Go/file.html

Thanks

Comment: Thats interesting, first time i have seen someone sharing a project. BTW i tried and it worked? What you want to not show? I just see some blank table for Match 20 onwards. Is that your issue?

Comment: Thank you, i thought it will be okay to share since it is a practice project, yes i am unable to hide those blank tables...

Comment: I have edited the question for clearity, my problem can be solved if those blank tables head can be hidden, Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a check for the table header as well. That is what you are missing here. I have added check for the table and the header (h3 tag), assuming data for each section will be of same year.

However, I believe you should have handled it differently using some filter (process the data in controller before passing this to html)

```js
<p class="mypara">Filters :</p>
<h3>2015 {{vm.isChecked2015}} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked2015" value="2015"></h3>

<div>
  <div class="table-responsive" dir-paginate="data in vm.rounds.concat(vm.rounds1) | itemsPerPage: 50" class="col-12 text-center" ng-if="isChecked2015">
      <table class="table table-sm table-dark" ng-if="data.matches[0].date.slice(0,4) == 2015">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th scope="col" class="p-3"># -- {{vm.isChecked2015}}</th>
          <th scope="col" class="p-3">Date -1</th>
          <th scope="col" class="p-3">Team1</th>
          <th scope="col" class="p-3">Score</th>
          <th scope="col" class="p-3">Team2</th>
          <th scope="col" class="p-3">Winner Team</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <div ng-if="data.matches[0].date.slice(0,4) == 2015"><h3>{{data.name}}</h3>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="matchday in data.matches track by $index">
            <th scope="row" class="p-3">{{$index+1}}</th>
            <td class="p-3">{{matchday.date}}</td>
            <td class="p-3">{{matchday.team1.name}}</td>
            <td class="p-3"><span ng-class="{won: matchday.score1 > matchday.score2, lost:matchday.score1 < matchday.score2, equal:matchday.score2 == matchday.score1}">{{matchday.score1}}</span><span class="vs">VS</span><span ng-class="{won: matchday.score2 > matchday.score1, lost:matchday.score2 < matchday.score1, equal:matchday.score2 == matchday.score1}">{{matchday.score2}}</span></td>
            <td class="p-3">{{matchday.team2.name}}</td>
            <td class="p-3" ng-show="matchday.score1 > matchday.score2">{{matchday.team1.name}}</td>
            <td class="p-3" ng-show="matchday.score2 > matchday.score1">{{matchday.team2.name}}</td>
            <td class="p-3" ng-show="matchday.score1 == matchday.score2">Draw</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </div>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
<dir-pagination-controls template-url="angular/templates/pagination.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

Comment: Thanks mate you solved my problem, now i will try to pass data from the controller to solve the pagination issue :)